# Batch parameters for installing OpenSSL 1.0.1?

Tags: command-line-interface, openssl, batch

I have a group of prereq programs that need to be installed on multiple computers. I have automated everything with a single batch file except for OpenSSL, which still requires a user to go through the GUI installer prompts. Are there any parameters or flags that can be passed to the installer to set the default directory and other flags? For instance, I use the following for another prereq for a silent install:

```
start /wait vcredist_x86.exe /qb
```

The installer is provided to us, so I can't rebuild the installer or anything easy like that. My searches for command line parameters only show me results for interactions after the install, not the installation itself. Any tips or directions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenSSL team [doesn't actually distribute any binaries](https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html) or installers for any platform. They rely on third parties for that.  So you need to consult whoever provided the installer that you're using to find out if there are any unattended ways to install their package.

Regarding the use of OpenSSL 1.0.1, here's a warning from their [site](https://www.openssl.org/source/):

> Note: The latest stable version is the 1.1.0 series of releases. Also available is the 1.0.2 series. This is also our Long Term Support (LTS) version (support will be provided until 31st December 2019). The 1.0.1 version is currently only receiving security bug fixes and all support will be discontinued for this version on 31st December 2016. The 0.9.8 and 1.0.0 versions are now out of support and should not be used.

So your organization should really look at upgrading to at least 1.0.2 so you don't find yourself relying on a version that is no longer being supported.